# Convert Normal Bootstrap Template to Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I have template which has certain files:

```
Home
--css
--fonts
--images
--js
--scss
-index.html
-blog.html
```

I want to convert that template to angular components but i'm not sure where should i keep those additional JS, SASS, Jquery files.

Please Suggest appropriate way to make it angular template without affecting original template.

I tried to create components and added appropriate CSS with it, still i cant figure out where to kept JS files and SASS files which essential to make template stable.

I expect the bootstrap template to be converted into Angular App.

Comment: You use the term "template" very loosely here, not sure what you mean by it. Angular doesn't replace Bootstrap in any way, you can still use bootstrap with Angular. Also, Angular doesn't use jquery

Comment: But to answer your question, Angular is a javascript framework which is probably meant to replace your javascript solutions that are "essential to make template stable". So you probably have to rethink your solution completely if you want to go with Angular. Look at the official documentation with the tutorials

Answer (score 3):

You could add css files, fonts and js files in src/assets.

Have a look at the following articles:

https://www.js-tutorials.com/angularjs-tutorial/convert-bootstrap-4-theme-angular-4-layout/

https://frensoltech.wordpress.com/2018/11/06/how-to-convert-html-template-to-angular-6-template/

Answer (score 0):

1. for Home page

you can create one component like home component and paste you're
    all body into home component, your header, footer and your external
    CSS and js in your index.html file (which is autogenerated by
    angular)

2. for the blog page

just create the blog component and copy the content without header and footer and paste in blog-component.html file